# Can't connect to network drives from explorer on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, windows-explorer

I used to have no problem connecting to local network drives from my work laptop, but I suddenly stopped being able to. I *am* able to connect from my desktop computer (also windows 7) which is connected to the same port through a switch.

When I connect, i'm directly using the ip address like this:
`\\***.***.***.**`
`\\***.***.***.**\bob\here\`

pinging the IP works fine:

```
Pinging ***.***.***.** with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ***.***.***.**: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from ***.***.***.**: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from ***.***.***.**: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from ***.***.***.**: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for ***.***.***.**:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

However when I try to connect from explorer, I get:
[image]

Or:

[image]

Or:

[image]

Comment: Is this on a domain network?

Comment: yes, it is on a domain network